# mdadm raid5 starts recovery right after creation

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid5

just for getting some experience with mdadm I've put some HDD together and try a bit. I have 2 250 GB and one 500 GB HDD. I know thats not optimal for RAID5 and I'll only get 500 GB capacity in total. 250 GB of 500 GB HDD is wasted. But as I said, I'm just playing around a bit.

First lets see the disk sizes:

```
lsblk /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb    8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk
sdc    8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
sdd    8:48   0 232.9G  0 disk
```

Create the RAID5:

```
sudo mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd -c 4 --auto md
```

Show info for created Raid5:

```
cat /proc/mdstat                                     Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdd[3] sdc[1] sdb[0]
      488132976 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 4k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [UU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.5% (1354384/244066488) finish=59.7min speed=67719K/sec
      bitmap: 0/2 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

Show a bit more details:

```
 sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Wed Feb 26 14:52:54 2020
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 488132976 (465.52 GiB 499.85 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 244066488 (232.76 GiB 249.92 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Feb 26 14:57:43 2020
             State : clean, degraded, recovering
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 4K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 7% complete

              Name : raspberrypi:0  (local to host raspberrypi)
              UUID : 3291b54e:fad8f43b:cc398574:a1845ff9
            Events : 57

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       16        0      active sync   /dev/sdb
       1       8       32        1      active sync   /dev/sdc
       3       8       48        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdd
```

Dmesg shows

```
[ 2462.122882] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 1
[ 2462.122892] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 0
[ 2462.126278] md/raid:md0: raid level 5 active with 2 out of 3 devices, algorithm 2
[ 2462.142439] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 499848167424
[ 2462.222689] md: recovery of RAID array md0
```

So what am I doing wrong with the creation of RAID5? I'm also confused in output of `mdadm --detail /dev/md0` with disknumber 0, 1 and 3 and not 0, 1, 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behavior for a newly created RAID5 array: just after creation, it *needs* to compute the correct parity for each stripe.

You can append `--assume-clean` to your `mdadm` command to skip the initial sync, but I strongly suggest against it: if your parity does not match, any `check` will report thousands of errors, and you will be unable to recognize real error from "fake" ones. To fix this very ambiguous situation, you need to run a `repair` command - which will recompute parity just as the initial array creation does.

Comment: While this initial rebuilt iotop shows most of the time 0 B/s ioactivity , same for htop.
`Total DISK READ:         0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE:         0.00 B/s
Current DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Current DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s`
However there's a lot disk activity going on. Why isn't it shown?

Comment: Raid resync happens at kernel level, and `iotop` sometime seems to miss kernel I/O. Can you try with `dstat -d -f` or `iostat -x -k 1` ?

Comment: Thanks `iostat -x -k 1` works.  `dstat -d -f` prints terminal too small (on a FullHD monitor).

Comment: Try with `dstat -d` then

Comment: Thank you. That works.